# prove sets cardinality inequality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I need to prove that if $$ A , B $$ are infinite sets and it holds that : $$ |A| > |B| $$ then: $$ |A \backslash B| = |A| $$
I guess I just don't what can I say about the cardinality  of |A\B| except that it is less or equal to |A|. 
Thank you,

Noam

Answer (score 1):

This boils down to showing that if A and B are two infinite sets such that $|X|>|Y|$ then $|X \cup Y| = |X|$
To prove this, notice that $|X \cup Y| \ge |X|$ since the map $f: X \to X \cup Y, f(x) = x$ is injective but not necessarily surjective.
To prove that $|X \cup Y| \le |X|$, let $X = S \cup T$ where S and T are disjoint and $|S|= |T|$ since |S|= |X| there exist a bijection k from S to X, and because |T| > |Y| a surjective map m from T to Y is not injective, combining k and m in one function yields a surjective function from $X$ to $X \cup Y$, thus $|X \cup Y| \le |X|$.
This shows that $|X \cup Y| = |X|$.

Now to prove that |A\B| can't be less than |A| observe that $B \cup A \setminus B = A$. If $|A \setminus B|$ is less than $|A|$ then the union is less than $|A|$

Comment: Why is $\vert S\vert=\vert X\vert$?

Comment: I assumed I can break the set into two dijoint sets of the same cardinality, I guess I should prove that.

Comment: I know that this is true since for infinite cardinal numbers $\alpha,\beta$ you have $\alpha+\beta=\max\{\alpha,\beta\}$. It just seemed like you "cheated" a little bit by assuming this. Since then it is almost trivial to see the statement that Noam is asking for is true. But then again I have no idea what Noam already knows about cardinal number arithmetic.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Basically, I know cardinal number arithmetic but I still not sure I understand your proof, why is this "combining k and m in one function yields a surjective function from $$X$$ to $$X∪Y$$, thus $$|X∪Y|≤|X|$$. This shows that $$|X∪Y|=|X||X∪Y|=|X|$$." true? and also why is this "observe that $$B∪A∖B = A$$" true?

Comment: The first map is surjective because if x is in $X \cup Y$, it is either in $X$ or $Y$, if it's in X it has a preimage in S, if it's in Y it has a preimage in T. Draw a Venn diagram to see the last identity.